VS Code not recognizing classes defined in .class files, but compiles fine in terminal
The starter folder for one of my assignments includes two files: DoublyLinkedNode.class and DoublyLinkedList.class , each with a declaration and implementation for the respective classes.
I want to create a class in a new .java file that extends DoublyLinkedList
public class DoublyLinkedListWithDummy<E> extends DoublyLinkedList<E> {

}

But VS Code flags DoublyLinkedList<E>  with
DoublyLinkedList cannot be resolved to a typeJava(16777218)

cannot find symbol
  symbol: class DoublyLinkedList(errors(1): 1:51-1:67)

DoublyLinkedListWithDummy.java compiles and even runs just fine when done manually from the terminal, but refuses to compile in VS Code due to the error above.

For context, here is my file directory. All the files are in the same directory, so they should be accessible to each other. And they clearly are, because on terminal it compiles fine.

Here are my classpath project settings. The source path is set correctly, as far as I can tell.


What could be causing this, and how do I make VS Code cooperate?
I tried resetting the workspace, checking source path, restarting VS Code, updating the Java Extension Pack, etc. None of these have worked.
Thank you!

You could use command Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace. If it doesn't work, you could add a .classpath file in the root of your project with the correct paths:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
  <!-- Add any additional libraries if needed -->
</classpath>

